# How to execute a binary from an android app with targetSdk > 28

Tags: android, binary

Everything is in the title, I ran into the same issue as the person in this topic :

[Android: Execute binary from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67974978/android-execute-binary-from-application)

However no solution was found and I would like to be able to target newer SDK.
If my traget SDK is higher than 28, I get an error 13, permission denied when running the binary from the app Runtime.
Thanks in advance